# Check if Exists and pull ID in one step

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm checking a SQL Server database if a `MemberID` exists based on a `WHERE` clause

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT MemberID FROM ADMIN_Biosketch_Members 
           WHERE emailAddress = @emailaddress)
```

And if it exists, I need that value to insert into another table:

```
SELECT @MemberID = MemberID 
FROM ADMIN_Biosketch_Members 
WHERE emailAddress = @emailaddress
```

Is there a way that I can do this in one step? I tried

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT @MemberID = MemberID 
           FROM ADMIN_Biosketch_Members 
           WHERE emailAddress = @emailaddress)
```

But it did not like that.

Thanks

Comment: try to put your insert in then with if exist condition

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can check for `NULL` after you fetch the value:

```
SELECT @MemberID = MemberID 
FROM ADMIN_Biosketch_Members 
WHERE emailAddress = @emailaddress

IF @MemberID IS NOT NULL
    -- value exists --> do something with it
```

If the `@emailaddress` value is not present in your table, then the `@MemberID` becomes `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do it like below instead of using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT @MemberID = MemberID FROM ADMIN_Biosketch_Members WHERE emailAddress = @emailaddress

if @MemberID is not null
  begin
  --your sql
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you searching something like that

```
-- this is your current table
create table #tmp (ID int, Name nvarchar(100))

insert into #tmp select 1, 'John'
insert into #tmp select 2, 'Andrey'
insert into #tmp select 3, 'Daniel'

-- this new table where you should insert your value
create table #tmp2 (ID int, Name nvarchar(100))

-- trick with inserting in case if it exists
insert into #tmp2
select *
from #tmp t
where t.ID in (select t2.ID from #tmp t2 where t2.ID = 3)

select *
from #tmp2
```

in your case it will look like

```
insert into ADMIN_Biosketch_Members_NEW(MemberID)
select MemberID
from ADMIN_Biosketch_Members t
where t.MemberID in (select t2.MemberID from ADMIN_Biosketch_Members t2 WHERE t2.emailAddress = @emailaddress)
```